# Angularjs и SEO

Tags: angularjs, seo

Например я разрабатываю синглпейдж приложение на angularjs. Соответственно google bot не сможет распознавать переходы по страницам и считывать meta title и description. Значить СЕО по сути не будет корректно работать, как можно решить эту проблему? прошу строго не судить, мало опыта в этом деле

Comment: как раз гугл-бот с некоторых пор js вполне прожует

Comment: @kroder а где можно пример реализации посмотреть, или почитать документацию, что-бы точно для себя выяснить?

Comment: ну ключевые слова angular prerender, т.е. идея в том, что на сервере генерятся статик-страницы, которые будут подсунуты поисковику

Comment: @kroder тойсть все запросы на сервер будут перенаправляться на  `RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)?$ http://prerender.herokuapp.com/http://www.yourdomain.com/prerender-test/$1 [P,L]`  как на примере Apache. Но если сайт очень нагружен и количество запросов превышает 50 тис

Comment: не, руками ничего никуда редиректить не нужно. или берем готовое решение, которое там по юзер-агенту будет на лету рендерить и подсовывать, или полагаемся в ангуляре на _escaped_fragment_ пререндер и поисковик там сам дернет какие ему надо страницы